# Compute Reock geometric compactness C++

Tags: c++, geometry, stdvector, stdarray

I need to be able to calculate the Reock compactness value for an arbitrary polygon (guaranteed to be simple). This value is defined as the ratio of the polygon's area to the area of its minimum bounding circle. I have the following data structure:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
typedef array<int, 2> coordinate;

class Polygon {
    vector<coordinate> border; // contains all coordinates
    double get_area();
    // a bunch of other data here...
};

class Polygon_Group {
    vector<Polygon> borders;
    double get_area();
};
```

This structure cannot be changed. I need a way to find the Reock score for an object of type `Polygon_Group`, and I need it to be as fast as possible. I have played around with [Miniball](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/subdir/software/miniball.html) for this, but it is really quite slow for me with large amounts of points. (Here's a small example of my miniball code)

```cpp
#include "Miniball.hpp"
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double> >::const_iterator PointIterator; 
typedef std::vector<double>::const_iterator CoordIterator;
typedef Miniball::Miniball <Miniball::CoordAccessor<PointIterator, CoordIterator> > MB;

double get_reock(Polygon_Group pg) {
    // the list of points as vector<int, 2>
    vector<coordinate> lp;
    // the list of points as vector<double>, because
    // through experimentation, this was all that worked
    vector<vector<double> > p; 

    for (Polygon poly : pg.borders) {
        lp.insert(lp.end(), poly.border.begin(), poly.border.end());
    }

    p.reserve(lp.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < lp.size(); i++) {
        p.emplace_back(lp[i].begin(), lp[i].end());
    }
    lp.clear();

    MB mb (2, p.begin(), p.end());
    return (pg.get_area() / (mb.squared_radius() * PI));
}
```

As stated above, this function was too slow for my needs (taking 0.4 seconds in some cases).
Really, what I need to know is how to quickly collapse the all the points in Polygon_Group into some sort of list, and then have some way to find the minimum bounding circle of those points. I can handle the area myself.

Comment: How many points are you talking?  Are they ordered in any way (clockwise, counter clockwise, etc.) Would be way simpler if you had the center of your poly, but I guess that is part of the fun here?  Also, have you profiled the code to see where it is spending that 0.4 seconds?  That will give insight on how perhaps to improve the given code.

Comment: Looked over the code and it isn't too bad.  I'd also ask then what compiler you used for your tests, did you use an optimized build with vectorization enabled, and can you just buy a faster system?   There is a chance that the algorithm could be made multi threaded and use a divide and conquer type method, but that would takes some time to do (and looks like it would advance the state of the art honestly.)

Comment: I am unable to run tests on the code right now, but I will test this in a bit and try to profile the code. This is using the g++ compiler, with `-0fast` optimization. Why would it be simpler if I had the center of the polygon? I do have a method to calculate this.

Comment: With center, you can do a distance squared check to each poly point.  Track the furthest from center.  When done, furthest point is a radius from center of a circle that will contain the poly.  That should be really, really fast.  Just multiplies, adds, and one square root at the very end to get the final radius from the radius squared.

Comment: g++ is gcc in C++ mode.  You should also be able to use -O3 instead of -Ofast (never heard of that flag and cannot find info, but maybe its ok?)

Comment: By center, I assume you mean the centroid of the union of the polygons in a `Polygon_Group`? Also I will use -O3 since from what you say it sounds more standard.

Comment: I can work with that.  If you don't have the center, calculating that may be slower than the algorithm you are using , so beware.  The neat thing though is that the algorithm I described can be made multi threaded rather easily as well.  Divide the poly into equal parts per CPU, find the largest radius squared in each group, then compare each core's maximum radius found and keep the biggest.  I will think about this further as well as it is a fun problem :)